# Manifold $M$ and affine scheme $\text{Spec}(C^\infty(M))$.

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, schemes, affine-schemes

Let $M$ be a $C^\infty$ manifold, $C^\infty(M)$ be its function ring and $X=\text{Spec}(C^\infty(M))$ be the corresponding affine scheme.

Both $M$ and $X$ are locally ringed spaces. Are they isomorphic? If not, is it possible to reconstruct $M$ from $X$?

Comment: $X$ and $C^\infty(M)$ have exactly the same information, so you can take a look to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1764947/can-we-recover-a-compact-smooth-manifold-from-its-ring-of-smooth-functions for answers to your second question.

Comment: And the comment by Eric Wofsey to Mike Miller's answer (in the link) will answer your 1st question.