# Example of $\mathbb R$-points of a manifold, which is not an actual point.

Tags: manifolds

A naive question inspired by the idea in algebraic geometry.

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold (second countable and Hausdorff), not assuming compactness. Let $C^\infty(M)$ be the ring of smooth functions. Define an $\mathbb R$-point of $M$ as a ring map
$$C^\infty(M)\to\mathbb R. $$

The first examples of $\mathbb R$-points are the *real points*, i.e. for $p\in M$, the evaluation is an $\mathbb R$-point
$$\mathrm{ev}_p:C^\infty(M)\to\mathbb R,\quad f\mapsto f(p). $$

The existence of local cut-off function and coordinate functions proves that $p\mapsto \mathrm{ev}_p$ is injective.

I want to understand the relations between $\mathbb R$-points and real points of $M$. Here are some natural questions:

- Is $p\mapsto \mathrm{ev}_p$ surjective? I tend to believe it false if $M$ is not compact. But counterexamples are not available to me.
- If the truth above depends on $M$, can you give sufficient conditions (or examples) in both cases?
- Any meaningful geometric structure on the $\mathbb R$-points, such as a topology?

Thanks.

Comment: Additionally, three answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1764947/can-we-recover-a-compact-smooth-manifold-from-its-ring-of-smooth-functions?rq=1) do not assume compactness, only the 2nd countability axiom, which is the standard assumption for smooth manifolds.