# Smooth map is diffeomorphism iff its pullback is an algebra isomorphism?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, diffeomorphism

newbie here in Diff Geo/Man!

I am given topological spaces $M$ and $N$, their algebras of continuous functions, $C(M), C(N)$, respectively, and a map $F^* = — \circ F : C(N) \to C(M)$, which is easily seen to be an algebra homomorphism. Also easy to see is that $F$ is smooth iff $F^*[C^\infty(N)] \subseteq C^\infty(M)$.

Also easily verifiable is that íf $F$ is a diffeomorphism, then $F^*$ is an algebra isomorphism. The converse, however, keeps me awake. Probably because I am so close.

I attempted to focus only on (smooth) constant functions, say, $$\text{Const}(M) := \Gamma(M) := \{c_m : M \to \mathbb R \mid m \in M, \text{im}(c_m) = \{m\}\} \subset C^\infty(M)$$
(And similarly for $N$, of course.)

I also know/believe, is that íf an inverse to $F$ exists, we must have $(F^*)^{-1} = — \circ F^{-1}$. The problem is I haven't been able to construct $F^{-1}$...

So, for some harmless diagrams:

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
M @>{\mu_0}>> \text{Const}(M) @>{\iota_M|_{\Gamma(M)}}>> C^\infty(M) \\ 
@V{F}VV             @AA{F^*|_{\Gamma(N)}}A                  @AA{F^*}A\\
N @>{\nu_0}>> \text{Const}(N) @>{\iota_N|_{\Gamma(N)}}>> C^\infty(N) 
\end{CD}

(We may not even need the right square.) As $\mu_0 : M \to \Gamma(M), \, m_0 \mapsto (c_{m_0} : m \mapsto m₀)$ is in clear bijection with $M$, similar for $\nu_0$, I went out to construct the inverse $G$ of $F$ as follows:

$$G := \mu_0^{-1} \circ F^*|_{\Gamma(N)} \circ \nu_0 : N \to M.
$$

However, when I perform my calculation, even while realising that precomposing a constant map with any map, remains that constant map ($c_{F(m)} \circ F = c_{F(m)}$), I just get the wrong answer: let $m \in M$. Then

\begin{align*}
G \circ F(m) &= ((\mu_0^{-1} \circ F^*|_{\Gamma(N)} \circ \nu_0)\circ F)(m) = (\mu_0^{-1} \circ F^*|_{\Gamma(N)}) \circ \nu_0 (F(m)) \\ 
&=(\mu_0^{-1} \circ F^*|_{\Gamma(N)})(c_{F(m)}) = \mu_0^{-1}(c_{F(m)} \circ F) \\
&= \mu_0^{-1}(c_{F(m)}) = F(m) \neq m = \text{id}(m).
\end{align*}

Can anyone spot a mistake? It looked clear enough to me that we wouldn't have to incorporate the entire diagram, but perhaps I should have, and instead have worked with $(\iota_M|_{\Gamma(M)} \circ \mu_0)^{-1}$, but I didn't think it necessary.

Any input greatly appreciated! Cheers!

Comment: It doesn't make sense to talk about constant functions $c_m$ for $m\in M$ since the codomain of your functions is $\mathbb{R}$, not $M$.

Comment: Ahhh.... $h1τ.. That doesn't seem to allow a quick fix... It underpinned much of my argument >.'<. Do you see a fix within the context of my attempt, or must I get back to a clean blackboard..?

Comment: Yet, obviously many smooth functions áre constant, but they output a real number. Can’t we use that real number to get back home?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to get the inverse to just "pop out", I would show that $F$ is a bijection.  First, $F$ is injective since $F^*$ is surjective (if $F(x)=F(y)$ and $x\neq y$, then $F^*$ would not be surjective since its image would not contain any function that takes different values on $x$ and $y$).  Then to see that $F$ is surjective, let $x\in N$ and take $f\in C^\infty(N)$ that vanishes only at $x$.  Then $f$ is not a unit in the ring $C^\infty(N)$, so $F^*(f)$ is not a unit in the ring $C^\infty(M)$.  This means $f\circ F$ must vanish somewhere, which means exactly that $x$ must be in the image of $F$.

So, $F$ is a bijection, and now you can conclude that $F^{-1}$ is smooth since composition with it sends smooth functions to smooth functions (since composition with $F^{-1}$ is just given by $(F^*)^{-1}$).

(Alternatively, for something more along the lines of what you were trying, you can "extract" the points of $M$ from $C^\infty(M)$ by identifying $m\in M$ with the homomorphism $C^\infty(M)\to\mathbb{R}$ that takes a function and evaluates it at $m$.  This gives a stronger result, that *any* ring isomorphism $C^\infty(N)\to C^\infty(M)$ (which is not assumed to be given by composition with a map $M\to N$) is given by composition with a diffeomorphism $M\to N$.  See the answers to [Can we recover a compact smooth manifold from its ring of smooth functions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1764947/can-we-recover-a-compact-smooth-manifold-from-its-ring-of-smooth-functions) for more details on this.)